# Replace CSS "#" (ID) with .(Class)

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I've a CSS string like

```css
    #xyz{
          color:#ee2ee2;
      }
     .abc{
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        border-color:1px solid #eee;
     }
    .def #xyz{
       border-color:1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

I need to replace the `#xyz` (or any other ID selector) with `.xyz` without changing the `color: #ee2ee2`(or any other color selector).
Basic java-script code would do

I've tried some regex but it fails a few cases

```js
cssText.replace(/#([a-zA-Z])/gm, '.$1');
```

Comment: Why can't you add `.xyz` to CSS?

Comment: I've a UI maker where a person can import their code and can create multiple components from the imported code. Since HTML doesn't support multiple IDs, I need to replace them with class

Comment: *UI maker* ... like WYSIWYG? I suppose that is a reason why you're doing this programmatically with client-side script, but it seems more a declarative or event driven scenario, rather then a post handling of some other activity.  You might want to get this implementation code reviewed on.  Having said that, this scenario that conditionally adds classes to elements should be minor.  Do you actually require regex, or is that just an implementation you're considering for this?

Comment: yes, it is a WYSIWYG builder(mostly), and regex is just a solution I am considering. Any other way would be great too.FYI, once I have replaced the CSS, I am sandboxing it using SCSS.

Comment: actually, I missed the remark in your comment regarding importing code.  in that scenario, you're validating and handling the imported code as a string? are you using a library or package to handle the uploaded data?   specifically something that parses the uploaded data into an XML DOM object that will better support XSLT and Xpath would be good here.

Comment: I don't want to change the nature of your question though: I think this question is still answerable under the concept of handling a string of imported HtmlFragment code using regex.  The result should be to remove id attribute and declaration, and add modify the class of the element to include that declared value.  it could be quite iterative since it will scan and match the string for each id match.

Comment: I purpose adding this "Text" to your question and relaying your expectation regarding it's outcome. [regexr.com sample](https://regexr.com/4o079)

Comment: actually.. I may have misread... seems you mean to handle a text\css file\content type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace `#` with `.` only when there is a `{` somewhere after in the same line.

```js
cssText = `
  #xyz
  {
     color:#ee2ee2;
  }
  .abc{
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
     border-color:1px solid #eee;
  }
  .def #xyz{
     border-color:1px solid #ddd;
  }
  body{background-color:#fff000;}.ig26{padding:20px;}.icts{width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;} 
`;
console.log(cssText.replace(/#([a-zA-Z])(?=[^}]*{)/g, '.$1'));
```

Comment: Note that `#foo \n {` is perfectly valid css.

Comment: As is `body { color: #ddd; } foo {` (note the absence of new lines.

Comment: As suggested by @JakubHampl doesn't work with : `body{background-color:.fff000;}.ig26{padding:20px;}.icts{width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;}`

Comment: yeah.. this is essentially right.. I do think it is more brittle then the expression I provided though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good job for regex. You will get much more reliable results by using a proper CSS parser. For example:

```js
const css = require('css');

const ast = css.parse(myInputString);

ast.stylesheet.rules.forEach(rule => {
  if (rule.type === 'rule') {
    rule.selectors = rule.selectors.map(selector => selector.replace('#', '.'))
  }
});

return css.stringify(ast);
```

(Note: I haven't fully tested this code. But the principle is solid.

Comment: Can you suggest a parse ?

Comment: referenced this answer's principal in my answer as a suggestion.  Since this answer essentially encompasses object and types (and is less specific on which library to use), I do think it's worth noting the CSSOM constructor draft\effort to standardize the construction of CSS Documents and Object Mapping. [git spec](https://wicg.github.io/construct-stylesheets/), [git explanation doc](https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md), [MDN CSSOM doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) as a set of API specifications.

Comment: If I could mark 2 answers as correct, I would have marked this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

By matching the spaces at the beginning of the line, you can use the regex `^\s+#(\w+)`.

Example in Java 13:

```
var regex = "^\\s+#(\\w+)";
var string = """
        #xyz{
              color:#ee2ee2;
          }
         .abc{
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            border-color:1px solid #eee;
         }
        .def #xyz{
           border-color:1px solid #ddd;
        }
    """;

var matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(string);
var newString = matcher.replaceAll(".$1");
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, though it fail in a few cases such as when there is a @media query, or when there is a sand-boxing of css.

Comment: in that case, you should update your question sample to include the `@media` query to deter answers that do not account for it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here is to use a library that might parse the object into rules, as suggested by @Jakub.

---

This answer uses the following regular expression, `/#(?!:[\w]+)(?=([\w\d\[\]\,\*\=\>\.\s]*[\{\,\[]+))/g`, which should effectively match `#` as it proceeds not-captured group (representing the Id itself) which in-turn proceeds the positive lookahead group (as series of word (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) and special characters, including whitespace & newline, that proceeds `{`, `,`, `[`).

```js
var outputElm = document.getElementById("output");

var importedCode = `div#xyz, #xyz, div#xyz[id='xyz'],
 .def>#xyz, .def>div#xyz, .def>#xyz,
 .def>div#xyz[id=*]
{
 color:#ee2ee2;
}


@media (min-width: 30em) and (orientation: landscape) 
{
  .abc{
      background-color :#FFFFFF;
      border-color:1px solid #eee ;
  }

  .def>#xyz, .def #xyz, .def>#xyz{border-color:1px solid #ddd;}
  .def>#xyz>div, .def #xyz div, .def>#xyz>div.abc {border-color:1px solid #ddd;}
}`;

var replaceIdRegex = /#(?!:[\w]+)(?=([\w\d\[\]\,\*\=\>\.\s]*[\{\,\[]+))/g;

outputElm.innerText = importedCode.replace(replaceIdRegex, ".");
```

```html
<p id="output">
</p>
```

I've done a fairly good amount of testing on this, but I can't say it isn't brittle or can account for every scenario.

---

You can test this implementation on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JX3QAv/4/) playground as well.