# Is there a way to style an element in React using the ID without using className?

Tags: css, reactjs, lamp

I am converting an old website into React, and do not want to have to change all the CSS files that were previously coded.  A lot of elements have their styles set currently by using an id.  Is there a way to get `className={styles["#topBar"]}` to set the style correctly without having to delete the `#` and replacing it with a `.` in the CSS folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656230/replace-css-id-with-class

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to change the #.  I just want to be able to use the CSS with the className

Comment: ids and classes have different specificities so either option is probably not recommended  and will quite likely not render as expected. [MDN Web Docs: Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I figured as much but was hoping there was a way.  Is there a way in React to style an element using the ID without using className?  Trying to avoid renaming a bunch of old attributes

Comment: Yes, just use it as normal in standard elements, and when passing it as a prop simply declare it as that prop name. `return (<div id="myID">)` or passed from props `<MyComponent id="compId" />` ... `MyComponent = ({id}) => {... return (<div id={id}>)}`. Docs: [All Supported HTML Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work though.  If I just have `<div id="top-bar">` in my HeaderToolbar.jsx file, no style is applied.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Hmm, I added a quick snippet to show it working. Without more information about your implementation it's hard to know why it's not working. Perhaps your CSS isn't being loaded globally? Or case issue in naming ("Top-Bar" vs "top-bar")?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are using CSS Modules you need to access the styles slightly differently. You need to `import styles from 'Component.module.css';` and then declare your styles by referencing this imported object `styles.MyClass` or in your case since you have hyphens you need to use bracket notation `styles["top-bar"]`

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ids-with-css-modules-in-react-eishp)

```
//MyComponent.js

import styles from "./MyComponent.module.css";

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div id={styles["top-bar"]}>
      <h2>My Component</h2>
      <InnerComponent id="inner" />
    </div>
  );
}

function InnerComponent({ id }) {
  return (
    <div id={styles[id]}>
      <h3>Inner Component</h3>
      <p id={styles.para}>Styled Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//MyComponent.module.css

#top-bar {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: LightPink;
}

#inner {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  text-align: left;
}

#para {
  color: red;
}
```

---

Here's a quick snippet showing it working with IDs.

```js
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div id="top-bar">
      <h2>My Component</h2>
      <InnerComponent id="inner" />
    </div>
  )
}

function InnerComponent({id}) {
  return (
    <div id={id}>
      <h3>Inner Component</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

```css
#top-bar {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: LightPink;
}

#inner {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="App"></div>
```

Comment: That's what I have.  Do you think it has something to do without the file being named HeaderToolbar.module.css?

Comment: HeaderToolbar.module.css is a scoped file that will only apply to the HeaderToolbar.js, so as long as `#top-bar {...}` is in that file and you've applied it in HeaderToolbar.js it should be applying.

Comment: Have you imported your style sheet into the .js file?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include using CSS modules.

Comment: That did it.  Should have thought of that.  Thank you so much.  Saved me a ton of work going through the css and changing everything